# Load increment and decrement input values on page refresh with local storage

Tags: html, jquery, local-storage, product-quantity

everyone!

I'm not sure if this has been asked here before.

What i'm trying to do is to change the quantity value of each item in my shopping cart by clicking the plus, and minus button. And save that value once I refresh the page using local storage. The problem is that once I refresh the page, the new input value is applied to other inputs in my shopping cart.

[GIF for better explaining my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdio0.gif)

Here is the simple version of my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    <button class="plus" data-qty="1">+</button>
    <input class="count" data-qty="1" type="number" min="1" max="5" value="1">
    <button class="minus" data-qty="1">-</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <button class="plus" data-qty="2">+</button>
    <input class="count" data-qty="2" type="number" min="1" max="5" value="1">
    <button class="minus" data-qty="2">-</button>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    let itemData = {
        itemQty: 1
    };

    if (localStorage.getItem("itemData") === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("itemData", JSON.stringify(itemData));
    }

    if(localStorage && localStorage.getItem('itemData')){
        var getItem = loadQuantity("itemData");
        $(".count").val(getItem.itemQty);
    }

    $(".plus").click(function(){
        var getItem = loadQuantity("itemData");
        getItem.itemQty = getItem.itemQty + 1;
        saveQuantity(getItem);
        $(this).closest(".item").find(".count").val(getItem.itemQty);
    });

    $(".minus").click(function(){
        var getItem = loadQuantity("itemData");
        if(getItem.itemQty != 1){
            getItem.itemQty = getItem.itemQty - 1;
        }
        saveQuantity(getItem);
        $(this).closest(".item").find(".count").val(getItem.itemQty);
    });

    function saveQuantity(data) {
        localStorage.setItem("itemData", JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    function loadQuantity(key) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem(key) != null) {
        loadQuantity();
    }
</script>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Make your code run here on stackoverflow.

Comment: The selector ".count" at $(".count").val(getItem.itemQty); returns both input-elements. So the values of both inputs will be set with the passed number.

Comment: @cpt.oneeye I think you're right. But what do you suggest would be the best thing to do and fix this? thank you!

Comment: @FSDford I'm sorry, but I have no idea how to do that here.

Comment: Here is your code in a jsfiddle.  It looks like there is an error, but I can't see what's going on.  Maybe you or someone else can figure it more easily from here.  https://jsfiddle.net/aw5kv39m/  Is there a missing semicolon?

Comment: key is not defined.

Comment: @alihoo i added a suggestion as answer.

Comment: @FSDford thank you for your code. But it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only store one value for several different inputs. You need to identify each value for each input seperately.

**HTML**

Add a unique attribute "data-key". Or you can use the "id" of each element.

```
<div class="item">
    <button class="plus" data-qty="1">+</button>
    <input class="count" data-qty="1" type="number" min="1" max="5" value="1" data-key="myInput1"> <!-- add a unique key -->
    <button class="minus" data-qty="1">-</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <button class="plus" data-qty="2">+</button>
    <input class="count" data-qty="2" type="number" min="1" max="5" value="1" data-key="myInput2"> <!-- add a unique key -->
    <button class="minus" data-qty="2">-</button>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

I altered your code. See comments below. Now "data-key" is used as key for the localStorage.

```
<script>

    let itemData = {
        itemQty: 1
    };

    if (localStorage.getItem("itemData") === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("itemData", JSON.stringify(itemData));
    }

    // new code for initializing
    // parse all inputs and user their keys to find the corresponding itemdata
    var allinputs = $('.count');

    for (var i = 0; i < allinputs.length; i++) {

        // get data according to "data-key"
        var getItem = loadQuantity($(allinputs[i]).attr('data-key'));
       
        if (getItem != null) {
            $(allinputs[i]).val(getItem.itemQty);
        } else {
            // data not existing. Set global default value
            saveQuantity(JSON.stringify(itemData), $(allinputs[i]).attr('data-key')); // *1 set first parameter just to itemData
        }
    }


    $(".plus").click(function () {

        // use key to get itemdata of this input
        var keyOfInput = $(this).closest(".item").find(".count").attr('data-key');

        var getItem = loadQuantity(keyOfInput);
        getItem.itemQty = getItem.itemQty + 1;
        saveQuantity(getItem, keyOfInput);
        $(this).closest(".item").find(".count").val(getItem.itemQty);
    });

    $(".minus").click(function () {

        // use key to get itemdata of this input
        var keyOfInput = $(this).closest(".item").find(".count").attr('data-key');

        var getItem = loadQuantity(keyOfInput);

        if(getItem.itemQty != 1){
            getItem.itemQty = getItem.itemQty - 1;
        }

        saveQuantity(getItem, keyOfInput);
        $(this).closest(".item").find(".count").val(getItem.itemQty);
    });

    // added new parameter "key"
    function saveQuantity(data, key) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    function loadQuantity(key) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)); // *2 Change to JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)));
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and code. But this code doesnt work. The quantity number disappears once i click the plus button. Thank you again.

Comment: It's strange. The code works fine on my browser at home. But i had the same effect on the browser at work (both Chrome). The problem ist the loadQuantity sometimes returns a string instead of an object and then you can not access the getItem.itemQty.

Comment: I added two changes in the code marked with *1 and *2. Try one of these. I think it is because that at *1 the object get's stringified two times.

Comment: @cpt.oneeye DUDE!!!!!! you're a genius!!!!! This worked perfectly. Thank you for your time!